Intellij Idea change backquote and programming language colour in codefence
I want to change the colour for  triple backquote and programming language indicator.
It seems like there are no colour settings for triple backquote and programming language in code fence settings in Editor > Color Scheme > Markdownn > Code.
Assume that this is maybe customised with CSS settings for Markdown, but not sure about it.

